# Can any one tell how can i format text value of a text box

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi all i am doing a program to round the text entered in a text box . Sample inputs

```
Entered value      output value
  100                100.00
   50                 50.00
```

Like this i would like to format my text box value on `textBox1_Leave` event

I tried this but didn't work for me

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = string.Format(textBox1.Text, "##.00");
    textBox1.Text = str;
}
```

Can any one help me

Comment: First, your examples don't really show rounding. What you mean *"it didn't work for me"*?

Comment: What does it mean when you say "didn't work"?

Comment: I am not getting the expected result

Comment: So, what **are** you getting? Errors? Other output?

Comment: What ever input i have given the same is getting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to convert that string to an number, *then* call Format.  Also, you were using format incorrectly.  You'll need to use a placeholder, like this

```
string str = String.Format("{0:F2}", Double.Parse(textBox1.Text));
textBox1.Text = str;
```

Naturally this will puke if you put in non-numeric input.  To allow for this, you can do some basic validation

```
double d = 0;            
textBox1.Text = 
       Double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out d) ? String.Format("{0:F2}", d) : "0";
```

Comment: Are you sure ToString() can be called like that? Text is of stype string and ToString now only accepts a Formatprovider. I think you have to convert to Double or whatever to have a ToString overload that accepts a formatstring

Comment: @rene - I *was* sure, until I tested it, then I wasn't so sure :)  - it's fixed now

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that your textbox value is already a string.  Try this:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var input = Convert.ToDouble(textbox1.Text);
    textBox1.Text = input.Tostring("#.00");
}
```

Note: you'll want to catch a format exception on the convert incase the input is not a number.